# How to reinstall and/or remove and install interrupted install of VisualSvn plugin in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, failed-installation, visualsvn

I started the install of the `VisualSvn` plug-in for `Visual Studio` before I realized that `Tortoise SVN` is a pre-req. I clicked the Cancel button, but I received the "Install Successful" dialog for `VisualSvn` anyway. However, when I started `Visual Studio`, the `VisualSVN` item is not on the menu bar. When I view `Visual Studio` `Extensions and Updates`, I don't see VisualSvn in the list. The kicker is that when I try and re-install `VisualSvn`, I cannot because `Visual Studio` does not appear as an app I can install `VisualSvn` on.

So, it seems `VisualSvn` is half-in/half out. Is there a way to make the `VSIX` installer forget and allow me to re-install `VisualSvn` over the top of what's already there?

p.s. I tried to restore my machine to a point immediately before the interrupted install, but a such a restore point is not available

Comment: what's your VS version? I tested it in my VS community 2017 and go to Extensions and Updates-Online to search and install this extension, the installation is successful like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCo3n3GCOhQ4nh5Y

Comment: VS 2017 Pro. The problem is that I tried to cancel the install after I started the install (see description above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we can also uninstall the extension from the command line using the VSIXInstaller.exe, I tried to the %temp% folder and find the installation log (VSIXInstaller_xxxxx) of this extension: [VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-Subversionintegration) to check the Identifier Id, then use the following command to manually uninstall this extension:

**vsixinstaller.exe /skuName:Pro /skuVersion:15.0.27130.2036 /u:VisualSVN.7D0F87F6-4A55-4C12-A903-998CF2ADFFE6**

The extension be uninstalled successfully as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank-you, the approach you suggested worked. I was able to uninstall VisualSVN successfully One difference: In my log file, I did not see the `skuname` or `skuversion` for Visual Studio, so I used this command with the VisualSVN Identifier I found in my log file: `vsixinstaller.exe /u:VisualSVN.7D0F87F6-4A55-4C12-A903-998CF2ADFFE6`